# PCIe - DMA: Consistent vs. Streaming Memory

Tags: linux, memory, driver, dma, pci-e

Currently I'm adding DMA to my PCIe driver for Linux. As I'm reading through the documentation it makes mention of consistent, or coherent, memory by using the API:

```
pci_set_consistent_dma_mask(...)
```

but never really talks about why to use it or what it does. It seems to mention to call the function for best practices and future proofing. The best I can gather is that consistent DMA memory does not have cache effects and the memory is written between device (FPGA) and CPU without any software/driver intervention once set up correctly (assuming I read correctly).
So my questions are:

1. Assuming a PCIe device does not require consistent memory then why would anyone use it, or in what cases is consistent memory used?
2. If I use consistent memory then do I **not** need to implement an interrupt in the PCIe driver for DMA? If true, then how does the userpsace code and device know a transfer has occurred?
3. If I transfer a lot of small packets, ~50 bytes, continuously and on occasion larger packets, ~6 kB, which DMA memory is better: consistent or streaming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about it this way: "Consistent" means it will be automatically coherent between CPU and bus *without doing anything to specifically synchronize it*. For example - say I have a memory ring for inbound and outbound packets. It's lifespan will be the entire time the system is in use, and I'm going to be checking it *all* the time. I want this to be *always* consistent, because if it isn't I would have to (manually) flush or synchronize the caches, and if this were costly, and I had to do this *very* time I touched the ring - it would be nightmare.

On the other hand - let's take a single data buffer I'm transferring. I't kind of a "one off" deal. I can let the device transfer it - and maybe it takes many PCI cycles to complete the DMA. And maybe this is *inconsistent*. That's okay - but when it's *done* I can flush/sync caches/force consistency. If it took a tiny bit of extra time to do so - no problem - because I'm just doing it *once*.

So you might ask "why not make everything consistent". Answer is there is generally *some* level of overhead to make things consistent. Depending on the architecture, this *could* be significant. So in such cases, there are provisions to allow for inconsistent (streaming) mappings which don't do cache consistency (but require an *explicit* sync). So allowing an inconsistent transfer could gain you some performance.

Remember too - there are some cases where you would *never* need any consistency. For example - reading a buffer from a network device to memory, then writing that memory to a disk controller. This data may never be read/used by the CPU at all - so why bother placing any overhead on the CPU cache to track it.

As for you comment about the "interrupt" - this is kind of odd. In a "normal" case - you might have a control structure in *consistent* memory (like a Tx/Rx rings) which you could *poll* to tell you if the transaction was done. But the actual data transferred would be in a *different* memory which could be streaming or non-consistent.

Comment: One thing I don't like in the first paragraph above: Network packet ring might not be a great example, because you don't necessarily want to touch packet payload. Better example might be an NVMe SQ or CQ ring. These rings have "control" data which is always being used by both CPU and end-device. So cache consistency is better than always explicitly flushing. These rings reference actual data buffers and those buffers may be or never be used by the CPU, and if so, only once at the end of a transfer. So those are "streaming", and may be suited to NOT being consistent, until flushed.

Comment: What do you make of the comment that "You may however need to make sure to flush the processor’s write buffers before telling devices to read that memory" here https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/dma-api.html#part-ia-using-large-dma-coherent-buffers? It sounds like it's not quite coherent...

Comment: I THINK they are eluding to the practice of doing a "readback" on/after the last byte of something you're writing to. This is for PCI ordering rules to assure that everything you wrote actually landed. For example - If the rules stated you needed to write a descriptor with source addr, dest addr land length to memory and then hit a "start" bit - you could write th aforementioned data in any order (or the processor might) - but you need to do a READBACK of the last piece of data before hitting the "start". If not, CPU might reorder things to that the "start" bit was written before the others.

Answer (score 1):

1)Imagine you want to transfer a huge amount of data via PCIE, with high rate. you have to use scatter/gather list, and you can use a consistent memory for prepare this list for FPGA, so FPGA can read this list very fast and then do the transmissions.

2)Of course you need interrupts, otherwise you have to use polling which is very slow and unreliable.

3)If you use larger consistent memory, you can minimize interrupt/polling overheads, so they are faster, but windows usually don't allow you to allocate large consistent memory.